# How to update/create new jwt after user changed username

Tags: django, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I use JWT(rest_framework_jwt module) in my project(backend: Django), now I allow user to change his/her username. As we known, after user changed username, the token will invalid(since the token(payload) include the username info, so the current local saved token cannot be used further). Then what we can do?

1. Logout? and let user re-login?
2. create new jwt? but how to do this since backend don't have the password(as I know, password is needed to create new jwt).

Comment: Who can help? Not sure why devote this ticket since I think this is meaningful question.